# Do I understand correctly 'too much', 'too many'

Tags: countability, quantifiers

First rule called 'countable' and 'uncountable'.

1. Use `too much` if uncountable i.e money, water.
2. Use `too many` if countable i.e dollar, table.

And second rule called `bad` and `good`.

3. If say `I have too much time` I mean `I have too much free time and I do not know what to do with it`.
4. And I say `I have a lot of time` I mean `I have too much free time and I do know that to do with it or I just enjoy`.

Do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question is exactly right: *too much money, too much water, too many dollars, too many lakes*.

As for "I have too much time" – by itself, that means something like, "I have so much free time I don't know what to do with it." So, I'd say that part of your question is correct as well.

The last part is where things get dicey. "I have a lot of time" (which could also be phrased as "I have plenty of time") generally means "I have a lot of *available* time," and that could be for any number of reasons – it's context dependent.  I would think that any of these questions or comments could be answered with, "Yes, I have a lot of time":

- *Thanks for helping me fix this lawn mower; do you have enough time to help me fix the wagon, too?* (In other words, *Do you have any remaining available time right now?*)
- *I was wondering if we could set up a meeting sometime next week.* (In other words, *Sometime in the future, will you have a block of available time?*)
- *Our football team needs a treasurer for the upcoming season. Could you volunteer?* (In other words, *Do you have enough available time that you could take on some short-term responsibility?*)
- *Could you take on a second part-time job in the evenings?* (In other words, *Does your schedule have enough free time that you could take on another activity on a regular basis for the foreseeable future?*)

And then there's the context you mentioned, where the answer might be "No, I have a lot of [free] time":

- *Are you so busy right now that your life is just completely hectic?*

So, "I have a lot of time" can mean several things, depending on the context.

Comment: Thanks. But I maybe wrong ask the question. If except word 'time' and say about other word i.e homework, money, friend'fake friend ? What to do when?

Comment: You would use "too much" homework and money, "too many" fake friends. But what constitutes "too much" or "too many" (as opposed to "just enough") is very subjective and vague, and therefore hard to quantify.

Comment: I get it from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFc6STGTU4w

Comment: She is giving good advice, but it's rare to say, "I have too much sugar." (If we're making cookies, for example, we use the sugar we need, and put the rest back in the pantry for later.) It's easier for me to imagine someone saying, "Oh, no – I put too much sugar into the cookie mix," or something like that.

Comment: Hyperglycemia isn't all that rare, is it?  :)

Comment: @Bob: Brilliant! Context is everything.

Answer (score 0):

A lot and too much mean two different things.  A lot simply means a large quantity; too much means a larger quantity than desired or appropriate.  "I paid a lot of money for the book" simply means the book was expensive; "I paid too much money for the book" means that I should have paid less money than I did.

"I have a lot of time" doesn't really imply anything one way or the other about knowing what to do with it.